# Leer desde una lista un archivo, guardar por cada item de la lista en un archivo

Tags: python, array, lista

me gustaría que el programa leyera un archivo txt donde están almacenadas las IP de los equipos (archivo aparte que el programa lo abra y lo recorra), y para cada equipo (IP) guarde en un archivo el resultado de los 2 comandos dados, en el momento lo tengo de esta forma que si me funciona correctamente. Si es posible, que no se tenga que pedir el nombre de usuario y clave, si no que estos datos también ya estén dados en el mismo programa, ejemplo: user= user1, y password=clave.

```
import paramiko
import getpass

def conectar_y_guardar(ip, usuario, clave, comando, archivo_salida):
    # Crear una instancia de la clase SSHClient de Paramiko
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

    # Configurar la política de aceptación automática de claves (esto es inseguro y solo se debe usar en entornos de prueba)
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    try:
        # Conectar al router Cisco
        ssh.connect(ip, username=usuario, password=clave, look_for_keys=False)

        # Ejecutar el comando y obtener la salida
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(comando)
        salida = stdout.read().decode('utf-8')

        # Guardar la salida en un archivo
        with open(archivo_salida, 'a') as archivo:
            archivo.write(f"\n\n======= {ip} =======\n\n")
            archivo.write(salida)

        print(f"Comando ejecutado en {ip} y salida guardada en {archivo_salida}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al conectar por SSH a {ip}: {e}")

    finally:
        # Cerrar la conexión SSH
        ssh.close()

# Configuración de la conexión SSH
usuario = input("Ingrese el nombre de usuario: ")
clave = getpass.getpass("Ingrese la contraseña: ")

# Lista de direcciones IP de routers Cisco
ips_routers = ["10.111.134.105", "10.111.134.157", "10.36.43.107"]

# Ejecutar comandos y guardar la salida en archivos separados
for ip in ips_routers:
    conectar_y_guardar(ip, usuario, clave, "show running", "output_show_version.txt")
    conectar_y_guardar(ip, usuario, clave, "show inventory", "output_show_inventory.txt")
```